# I am having issues with displaying my herocard when clicking on the button to scroll through a list of cards

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, arrays

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import data from "../data"

const Hero = () => {

    const [cards, setCards] = useState(data.data.pages);
    const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
    const [heroCard, setHeroCard] = useState(cards[0]);
    const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(false);


    const addHeroCards = () => {
        setActiveIndex(prev => activeIndex + 1);
        setHeroCard(prev => cards[activeIndex]);;
        if(activeIndex >= 3) {
            setHeroCard(prev => cards[3]);
        } 
    }

    const subtractHeroCards = () => {
        setActiveIndex(prev => activeIndex -1);
        setHeroCard(prev => cards[activeIndex]);
        if(activeIndex <= 0) {
            setHeroCard(prev => cards[0])
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="hero">
            <button className="btn one" onClick={subtractHeroCards} disabled={isDisabled}>&lt;</button>
            <div className="hero-title">
                    <h2>{heroCard.title}</h2>
                </div>
            <div className="hero-text">
                <p>
                    {heroCard.document}
                </p>
            </div>
            <button className="btn two" onClick={addHeroCards} disabled={isDisabled}>&gt;</button>
        </div>
    )
  }
  
  export default Hero;
```

I want to be able to click the button and display the next card or click a button and display the previous card but not go past the array of objects as it is currently doing.
I have created a disabled state but when it gets disabled I can't click on the button anymore and the active index goes past the intended index. or it doesn't display correctly.

I tried creating a disabled state

```
const addHeroCards = () => {
        setActiveIndex(prev => activeIndex + 1);
        setHeroCard(prev => cards[activeIndex]);;
        if(activeIndex >= 3) {
            setIsDisabled(true)
            setHeroCard(prev => cards[3]);
        } 
        setIsDisabled(false);
    }

    const subtractHeroCards = () => {
        setActiveIndex(prev => activeIndex -1);
        setHeroCard(prev => cards[activeIndex]);
        if(activeIndex <= 0) {
            setIsDisabled(true);
            setHeroCard(prev => cards[0])
        }
        setIsDisabled(false);
    }
```

and set it as false or true depending on the index but after it gets disabled the whole entire button doesn't act right. Plus I have to click on the button more than once the first time in order to get it to get to the next index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, these two set state functions are completed synchronously so setHeroCard may be using the old activeIndex instead of the new activeIndex. This may cause some weird issues with having to click buttons multiple times to update to the right values.

```
        setActiveIndex(prev => activeIndex + 1);
        setHeroCard(prev => cards[activeIndex]);;
```

To prevent the index from going past the size of the array, you could limit the index in your add and subtract functions.

```
    const addHeroCards = () => {
        if(activeIndex + 1 >= cards.length) return;
        ...

    const subtractHeroCards = () => {
        if(activeIndex <= 0) return;
        ...
```

To update the disabled state, you can base it on whether or not the index has reached the limits of the array.

```
    <button className="btn one" onClick={subtractHeroCards} disabled={activeIndex <= 0}>&lt;</button>
    <button className="btn two" onClick={addHeroCards} disabled={activeIndex + 1 >= cards.length}>&gt;</button>
```

So your code will look something like this. (Note: this code has not been tested)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import data from "../data"

const Hero = () => {

    const [cards, setCards] = useState(data.data.pages);
    const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
    const [heroCard, setHeroCard] = useState(data.data.pages[0]);

    const addHeroCards = () => {
        if (activeIndex + 1 >= cards.length) return;
        setHeroCard(cards[activeIndex + 1]);;
        setActiveIndex(activeIndex + 1);
    }

    const subtractHeroCards = () => {
        if(activeIndex <= 0) return;
        setHeroCard(cards[activeIndex - 1]);
        setActiveIndex(activeIndex - 1);
    }

    return (
        <div className="hero">
            <button className="btn one" onClick={subtractHeroCards} disabled={activeIndex <= 0}>&lt;</button>
            <div className="hero-title">
                    <h2>{heroCard.title}</h2>
                </div>
            <div className="hero-text">
                <p>
                    {heroCard.document}
                </p>
            </div>
            <button className="btn two" onClick={addHeroCards} disabled={activeIndex + 1 >= cards.length}>&gt;</button>
        </div>
    )
  }
  
  export default Hero;
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes this answers my question, thank you very much, may ask if you can explain the detail about setHeroCard(cards[activeIndex +1]); and then setActiveIndex(activeIndex +1); is there a reason for doing it this way ?

Comment: Hi, when you run setActiveIndex then setHeroCard, they do not run one after the other, so when the program hits setHeroCard the activeIndex may be incremented or may be the previous value.

Setting the active card to index+1 then setting the index to index+1 ensures that the active card will be selected properly.

Comment: If this answers your question can you please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick box under the question :)